# Slash before http ("/http://...") drupal

Tags: http, drupal

Hy. When I move my site to server I get this bug - Page "/http://..." not found. In local host avreverything ok. What could happen?

Comment: Sounds like a concatenation gone wrong. `Http://` is the protocol. It looks like your configuration is configuring it as a relative address and then appends the protocol.

Comment: U think it may be bad config in apache?

Answer (score 0):

Your domain site name must be mistype. In any website, there is no domain site nae that begin from `/http://...`. It must be `http://`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that an url starting with slash char "/" refers to HTTP_ROOT of your site.